# Question regarding isolated and embedded primary ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I am trying to understand the difference between isolated and embedded primary ideals.
An example we took a look at, was:

Let $\mathfrak{p}_1= (x)$, $\mathfrak{p}_2 = (x,y)$. Let $$\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{p}_1 \cap \mathfrak{p}_2^2 \\
= (x) \cap (x,y)^2 \\
= (x) \cap (x^2, xy,y^2)\\
 = (x) \cap (x^2,xy,y)\\
 = (x) \cap (x,y) = (x^2,xy)$$

And then in my script is written that $\mathfrak{p}_1$ is isolated and $\mathfrak{p}_2$ embedded. But why is the latter one embedded? How can one see this?

It would be great, if someone could explain me this.

Comment: $\mathfrak p_2$ being embedded just means that it is not a minimal prime in the primary decomposition. Here $\frak  p_2\supseteq\frak p_1$.

Comment: That means the primary ideals have always to be either minimal or embedded? And if it is not minimal, then it implies the embeddedness?

Comment: The terminology comes from the fact that each ideal has a zero set in the $xy$-plane, meaning that _all_ elements of the ideal, seen as polynomial functions, are zero at those points. For $(x)$, that is the $y$-axis, while for $(x,y)$ it is the origin. The origin is embedded in the $y$-axis, and we extend the terminology to the ideals (at least for prime ideals).

Comment: @Arthur Great, that clarifies my question! Thanks a lot! :)